# Permit only N connection for a user/config in openvpn

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I have openvpn on a server and a few client configs. How can I permit only a single connection for a user? Or if not necessarily single connection, but no more than N connections for user. I've not found anything regarding this matter in the documentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you provide your own connect scripts, you can control how many connections are allowed per user. The only catch is that you need to have a persistent storage of some kind. Note that the default behavior is to allow a client only once.

Here is what you need to do.

On the server, include the following lines in the config:

```
script-security 2
duplicate-cn
up /etc/openvpn/connectScript.sh
client-connect /etc/openvpn/connectScript.sh
client-disconnect /etc/openvpn/connectScript.sh
```

The `duplicate-cn` is needed for having simultaneous client connections, the `script-security 2` is needed for running external scripts.
On the client, you need to add the `explicit-exit-notify` option, because without that, the server won't receive a disconnect message when the client exits or disconnects, thus, the disconnect script will be called only upon timeout.

The following environmental variables will be exported for the script (along with others -- see the "Environmental Variables" section of the manpage of `openvpn`):

- `script_type` can be either `up`, `client-connect` or `client-disconnect`, depending on when the script is called.
- `common_name` will contain the name of the user connecting, that is, the value of the CN field of the certificate or the username, depending on what kind of authentication you have on the server.

If `script_type` is `up`, you need to clear all client connection data, since at that time openvpn just started, and no client connections are present.

If `script_type` is `client-connect`, then your script needs to decide if the user specified in the `common_name` variable has already been connected, and if so, how many times. If the connection is permitted, the script should exit with a value of 0. Any other exit value is interpreted as an error, and the client won't connect. So you need to count the clients with the same name, and exit with an error if there are too many connections for that user. You should decrease the count when `script_type` is `client-disconnect`.

You need to make sure that the script is runnable by the user who runs the `openvpn` process, which is preferably not root (specified by the `user` and `group` configuration variables).

Here is a sample connect script. using this, every client can have two connections, the third will be denied. This is a very primitive sample only, you should create a more sophisticated one, but it's a good start.

```
#!/bin/bash

PERSIST_DIR=/tmp/pDir
mkdir -p $PERSIST_DIR

function handle_connect {
  CLIENTFILE=$PERSIST_DIR/$common_name
  if [ -e "$CLIENTFILE" ]; then
     NUMCONN=$(cat $CLIENTFILE)
     NEWCONN=$(expr $NUMCONN + 1)
     if [ $NEWCONN -gt 2 ]; then exit 1; fi
     echo $NEWCONN >$CLIENTFILE
  else
     echo 1 >$CLIENTFILE
  fi
}

function handle_disconnect {
  CLIENTFILE=$PERSIST_DIR/$common_name
  if [ -e "$CLIENTFILE" ]; then
     NUMCONN=$(cat $CLIENTFILE)
     NEWCONN=$(expr $NUMCONN - 1)
     echo $NEWCONN >$CLIENTFILE
  fi
}

case "$script_type" in
  up)
        rm -f $PERSIST_DIR/*
        ;;
  client-connect)
        "handle_connect"
        ;;
  client-disconnect)
        "handle_disconnect"
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: Just wanted to genuinely thank you, I started my own business starting with your management script :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible with *password authentication*, as you can only limit global `max-clients`. However, this is default the behavior with *certificate authentication*.

```
# Uncomment this directive if multiple clients
# might connect with the same certificate/key
# files or common names.  This is recommended
# only for testing purposes.  For production use,
# each client should have its own certificate/key
# pair.
#
# IF YOU HAVE NOT GENERATED INDIVIDUAL
# CERTIFICATE/KEY PAIRS FOR EACH CLIENT,
# EACH HAVING ITS OWN UNIQUE "COMMON NAME",
# UNCOMMENT THIS LINE OUT.
;duplicate-cn
```

Using certificates for authentication is well explained in [OpenVPN PKI HOWTO](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#pki). While you need one client certificate per every client computer, you could allow more simultaneus connections for a single user by allocating him more certificates.

[image]

- The blue user has two computers and needs both `client1.crt` and `client2.crt` + keys + CA (for connecting them both at the same time: if there's no need for simultaneous use, 1 is enough).
- The red user has only one computer, so `client3.crt` + key + CA is enough.
- Clients don't need `server.crt` and the server doesn't need to know clients: they all trust the CA.

Comment: how can I allow only N clients with the same config?

Comment: `duplicate-cn` is a true/false value; you either allow unlimited or just one. If some of your users needs more than one simultaneus connection, provide more certificates.

Comment: does `duplicate-cn` allow 2 connections for the same client on different protocols: tcp and udp? if yes, how to setup that?

Comment: You could test, but probably not, because the setting is designed to prevent multiple connections, and the TCP/UDP option isn't related to this in any way.

Comment: ok. what certificate did you mean in your previous comment? there're a few files: ca, crt, pem, key -- which

Comment: That's too wide to answer in a comment. See [OpenVPN PKI HOWTO](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#pki).

Comment: I'm familiar with that. Which files exactly is that? client.crt or client.key or anything else?

Comment: Scroll further to **Key Files**. There's an informative table that answers this.

Comment: Reread my question.

Comment: ..Meditating..?

Comment: `client1.crt`: client1 only, Client1 Certificate, Secret: NO & `client1.key`:5 client1 only, Client1 Key Secret: YES... `ca.crt` server + all clients, Root CA certificate. All needed by a client computer, one key/crt per client.

Comment: A client already has all, I asked about **additional** files that you meant in `If some of your users needs more than one simultaneus connection, provide more certificates.` What's not clear? What `ca.crt` have to do with that? It's already generated initially and provided to a client.

Comment: If there must be one certificate per client device and an user needs to have two devices, you need to give him `clientN.crt` and `clientN+1.crt` and the keys. A single device probably doesn't need more than one + CA. I appreciate the name-calling after patiently guiding you to the correct tutorial.

Comment: `The red user has only one computer, so client3.crt + key + CA is enough.` -- what's the "key" here? client.key? server.key? ca.key?

Comment: Could it be the only key file marked with a red dot and explained in both "needed by" & "purpose" columns? On the other hand, if the `server.key` is "needed by server only" and the `ca.key` is "needed by the  key signing machine" alone, what makes you believe there's still room for confusion?

Comment: I tested with Password Auth and saw mutle users can login, but changing the login to just Certificate with no password only one user at a given time can login. And if user-1 logs in, meanwhile user-2 logs in, user-2 will have the connection and user-1 is dropped.

Comment: I tested with Password Auth and saw mutle users can login, but changing the login to just Certificate with no password only one user at a given time can login. And if user-1 logs in, meanwhile user-2 logs in, user-2 will have the connection and user-1 is dropped.